# How to debug 403 error on Cent OS?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualenv

I'm trying to install phpMyAdmin and I'm getting a 403.

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 99.232.55.0/24
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
      AllowOverride All
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 99.232.55.96
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

This is running on CentOS 6.6 on Apache 2.2

I've tried a ton of combinations and none of these files seem to make a difference. I have a feeling there is another file having effect but the logs say nothing about how to find it.

The Apache ErrorLog and AccessLog give nothing of use.

I am running a Django site inside of Virtual Env at the domain root.

Comment: Are you using selinux? If so something like `chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t -R /usr/share/phpMyAdmin` might help.

Comment: I ran that and there was no output.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any output from that command. Did it make any difference to the problem?

Comment: Also worth checking if `selinux` is enabled. What does `getenforce` say?

Comment: Yes it is enabled and getenforce says `Enforcing`

Comment: The first thing to do is to look at Apache's error log.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the filesystem permissions on the phpMyAdmin folder and its subfolders/files permit them to be read and directories have the execute (x) permission set on them such that the Apache user can traverse into them.